# Joint distribution from a differential equation

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations, continuity, expected-value, uniform-distribution

I have the following problem -

Z is a random variable which can take any real value in the range [0,1]

a and b are independent variables drawn from uniform distribution in the interval [0,1].

Z is a function of a and b - Z(a, b)

I have differential equation for $\frac{dZ(a, b)}{da}$ and $\frac{dZ(a, b)}{db}$. I computed partial Z(a, b) (partial because they just reflect change in Z with respect to one variable). Let's denote them by $Z_{a}(a, b) $ and $Z_{b}(a, b) $

I have to find complete Z(a, b)

Will it be -

Z(a, b) =  $Z_{a}(a, b) $*$Z_{b}(a, b) $ since a and b are independent

Or

Z(a,b) = prob(a)* $Z_{a}(a, b) $ + prob(b)*  $Z_{b}(a, b) $

I am confused. Any clarification will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly neither of those.  What is the function or the differential equation?

Comment: Why neither? Then how can we compute Z(a, b) from Z(a) and Z(b)? Differential equation forms a very long, tedious equation. But I just need the formula to compute Z(a, b). How does equational form matter?

Comment: What do you even thing $Z(a)$ means when $Z$ is a function of $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: Z(a) is basically $Z_{a}(a, b)$ - marginal pdf.

Comment: So, let me explain my problem. I recovered Z(a, b) from two differential equation. But overall Z(a, b) will be an expectation computed from combining the two. How should the combination be is my question. Hope that clarifies